# how can function SUBSTR can help me remove vlues from my column

Tags: sql, oracle

25779101724|GTG1105-Kibimba .These are the telefone numbers, there is more like this.After the numbers the following characters are a location of the telefone number. so i want to remove everything after these numbers(the bar,the location, and the space) so that i can query in the db the numbers which are active among these. and then i dont want to lose these location after numbers because i will need them to report the active numbers AND their location. how can i remove these location and query the active numbers and then replace the location.
I am hoping a response.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

From my point of view, your by far the best option is to normalize that table and store each piece of information into its own column. Because, as long as you can easily split that string into several parts, joining it to another table will suffer as number of rows gets higher.

Anyway, here you are.

Sample data:

```
SQL> with test (msisdn) as
  2    (select '25779101724|GTG1105-Kibimba' from dual union all
  3     select '25776030896|BRR1351-Kaberenge2' from dual
  4    )
```

Query begins here:

```
  5  select
  6    substr(msisdn, 1, instr(msisdn, '|') - 1) phone_number,
  7    substr(msisdn, instr(msisdn, '|') + 1) the_rest
  8  from test;

PHONE_NUMBER                   THE_REST
------------------------------ ------------------------------
25779101724                    GTG1105-Kibimba
25776030896                    BRR1351-Kaberenge2

SQL>
```